# save value returned by periodicalupdater

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want save the server response from the periodical updater as a string that I can then parse.If I put the alert inside the function everything works fine. However in the js code below the alert will show up blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<script>
var str='';
var on=new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater("onlinelist",
"manageuser.php?action=onlinelist",
{method:’get’,onSuccess:function(transport){str+=transport.responseText;},
frequence:1000});
alert(str);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your intention is there.

`onSuccess` method will fire once data is received successfully.

```
<script>
    var str='';
    var on=new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater("onlinelist",
        "manageuser.php?action=onlinelist",
        {
            method:"get",
            onSuccess:function(transport){
                str+=transport.responseText;

                // continue using once it is available
                doSomething(str);
            },
            frequence:1000
        });

    function doSomething(str) {
        // logic that requires str
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is I want to set the value of str inside on success but then use it later on

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you should pass the ```str``` value to a function that does rest of the work once ajax call is successful. As in the code sample above